# Flask: response returned event

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to execute a function after a response is received by the client?

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'hello'
    # perform some action after returning the response
```

I found [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/53/) snippet, but it only mutates the response *before* it has been returned.

Comment: Responses are not received from a client.. do you meant *returned to a client* perhaps?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not if I understand the difference. A request is received by the server and the response is delivered (and thus received) by the client... or is my terminology a bit off?

Comment: I am not clear why the snippet you found is not what you want. It is the last stage of returning the produced response to the client. After that point the response is written to the socket, there isn't any *later* point that you can do anything about the response.

Comment: Yes, that terminology is off. The response is delivered *to* the client. The client receives the response *from* the server.

Comment: Well, that's the answer then (+1). I was hoping there was a later stage (something that tells me that the client received the response).

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're trying to return a response immediately, but run a (longer-running?) function afterwards, you could call it via a task queue like Celery and then return your response